# How to listen to a port in Docker

Tags: docker, networking, port

I am new to networking so apologies if this question does not make sense. I have a web server that creates a stream of video on localhost port 80 (0.0.0.:80). I have a docker container that sends a request (through requests library) to start and capture the stream. The docker program asks for the port to send the request to, so the url is ("http://0.0.0.0:80"). The problem is that I need to do a -p to map the internal docker port to external host's port. so I do (-p 8082:80) which maps port 8082 of the host to the port 80 in the docker. and this is the error I get in the docker:

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /textdata (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

I cannot have -p 80:80 because docker is considered as a web server I believe, so anyone knows what is happening and what can I do to make this work? Needless to mention that it works outside of the container and it works if the web server which streams the video is in the docker, but does not work if the listener is inside a container.

Update: The sender is running at my host (outside of any container) and the receiver is in a docker container.

thank you

Comment: Is the streaming app in Docker? Or running on your localhost? Also trying to send data _to_ `0.0.0.0` is weird, and probably also wrong (as I believe that will just go to `127.0.0.1` which will be inside your 'sending' container which is not where your 'streaming' app is running).

Comment: There is no difference if the streamer is inside of a docker or not, both ways works. The localhost address 0.0.0.0 is mapped to 127.0.0.1 so both can be used as far as I know. These details can be changed. the sending container or web server has no problems, the receiver cannot reach to sender, it can reach if receiver is not in a container.

Comment: localhost in the container is not the same as localhost on your host. If the streamer is running on your host, and the python app is running in the container, hitting 127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0 is not going to work. Can you update your question with how you are running the apps / containers and where they are running more clearly please?